# Short story about if you die you are reborn as someone else in a different time

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I remember reading a short story a few years ago and I would like to reread read it again. As far as I remember it went a little like this:

You are in a car with your family and a truck hits it, but you are the only one to die. When you regain conciousness you are [in some place that I can't remember] and you see a person (I'm going to call the person as Bob from here, but it's possible the gender wasn't specified) and ask him about your wife/family, Bob tells you that you are dead and your wife/family are/will grieve for you for a time, but your wife get over you and marry someone else.
Bob then basically tells you that you are not actually a human but a being like him and their kind created the concept of the universe, time, ethics, morality etc for you because you are young and it will teach you the above.
 Since the universe is made just for you, everybody in the universe is you. When you die you are reborn as someone else on Earth, but the past memories are blocked but you do start to gain them back if you stay in the place you are in, but Bob wants to send you back to experience more because you are not finished just yet. 
One of the last things Bob says to you is that you will be born this time as a farm girl in China in X year.

I have tried Googling this, but I was only able to get results like "God did not create the universe, gravity did, says Stephen Hawking", "IS THERE A GOD?" and "Quotes About Universe". Any help would be great.

Comment: That's really creepy...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is "The Egg" by Andy Weir

You can read the full story online [here](http://www.galactanet.com/oneoff/theegg_mod.html)

> “How many times have I been reincarnated, then?”
>   “Oh lots. Lots and
>   lots. And in to lots of different lives.” I said. “This time around,
>   you’ll be a Chinese peasant girl in 540 AD.”
>    “Wait, what?” You
>   stammered. “You’re sending me back in time?”
>   “Well, I guess
>   technically. Time, as you know it, only exists in your universe.
>   Things are different where I come from.”

later

> “Because someday, you will become like me. Because that’s what you
>   are. You’re one of my kind. You’re my child.”
>
> “Whoa,” you said, incredulous. “You mean I’m a god?” “No. Not yet.
>   You’re a fetus. You’re still growing. Once you’ve lived every human
>   life throughout all time, you will have grown enough to be born.” “So
>   the whole universe,” you said, “it’s just…” “An egg.” I answered. “Now
>   it’s time for you to move on to your next life.”

Purely as a matter of interest, he recently did a Reddit AMA (Ask Me Anything) where he discusses the story [in some considerable detail](https://web.archive.org/web/20161027172927/http://rnm.gauzza.com/comments/zt1n6)

Comment: Perfect that is the story I was thinking of! Thanks so much :)