# scifi/fantasy story where main character lives many lives

Tags: story-identification

I read a book about ten years ago, in which the protagonist lives the life of many characters within the same time sequence. I think there are others who also do this and they agree that during each life they will not remember previous lives, or the fact that they have this god-like facility.

Comment: Would you please modify the title into a more expressive one? Also welcome to scifi&fantasy SE :-)

Comment: Was my answer the right one?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/73270/short-story-about-if-you-die-you-are-reborn-as-someone-else-in-a-different-time

Answer (score 3):

Could the be "The Egg" by Andy Weir?

You can read the full story online [here](http://www.galactanet.com/oneoff/theegg_mod.html)

> “How many times have I been reincarnated, then?”
>   “Oh lots. Lots and
>   lots. And in to lots of different lives.” I said. “This time around,
>   you’ll be a Chinese peasant girl in 540 AD.”
>    “Wait, what?” You
>   stammered. “You’re sending me back in time?”
>   “Well, I guess
>   technically. Time, as you know it, only exists in your universe.
>   Things are different where I come from.”

later

> “Because someday, you will become like me. Because that’s what you
>   are. You’re one of my kind. You’re my child.”
>
> “Whoa,” you said, incredulous. “You mean I’m a god?” “No. Not yet.
>   You’re a fetus. You’re still growing. Once you’ve lived every human
>   life throughout all time, you will have grown enough to be born.” “So
>   the whole universe,” you said, “it’s just…” “An egg.” I answered. “Now
>   it’s time for you to move on to your next life.”

Purely as a matter of interest, he recently did a Reddit AMA (Ask Me Anything) where he discusses the story [in some considerable detail](http://rnm.gauzza.com/comments/zt1n6)