# Help identifying a short SF about living the life of all human beings

Tags: story-identification, novel

Here's a novel that I cannot recall correctly the name. It'll be great if someone could help identifying its name.

WARNING: POTENTIAL SPOILERS BELOW

Hints:

1. It's a short novel.
2. The main idea is that an individual lives the life of all human beings (to be explained below).
3. Here's the storyline that I recall (sorry but it might be different from the actual novel, as I may make mistakes in memory):

   - There was an individual A who lived his whole life and died.
   - After his death, he met an angel, who told him that he would be re-born and start a life as another person B.
   - The same individual then lived through the whole life of B. After his death, he met the same angel.
   - Then the same process repeated. The same individual lived lives of another person C, another person D, and so on.
   - The same angel then revealed it: All those billions of people, past, present, and future, were all this same person experiencing different phases / roles. And when he / she finished experiencing all lives of human beings, he / she would eventually become one of the *real humans*, just like this angel itself.
4. I read it in the Chinese language. But I cannot now recall whether it's written by a Chinese author, or translated into Chinese.
5. I didn't read the story from a book. I probably read it on my kindle or my laptop.

Comment: Welcome to the site. You have a good start here. If you could take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] in any more details, that would be great. Every little bit helps us.

Comment: @amflare Thanks a lot for the hint. :) I've updated the question with a few more hints after reading the guide. I do not remember any further detail at this moment, and I'll come back updating the question if I do later.

Comment: As usual, it's [The Egg by Andy Weir](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/73272/20774)

Comment: Ah.. right. @Valorum could you make it an answer? Or I don't know how to mark this as resolved..

Comment: Done. Glad you found your answer!